# Handle npm module error on nodejs version upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

If I upgrade `nodejs` version on a server which brings some new changes due to which:

- a `npm package` which is used in the process with its current version,
  is now giving some error and server is down.
- And that `npm module` can take days to get compatible with this node
  latest version.

In the meantime what should I do to up the server, I don't have time to remove the module and all of its functions used.

This is more of a generic question and not specific to any npm module.

Comment: You can have look at **[`NVM`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)** that can manage `node` version switching for the system (server).

Comment: Can you post the error...? This also might help (and expands on Ambian's comment) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976145/update-nodejs-in-production-with-zero-downtime

Comment: @Devnetics thanks for the link, but there is no such specific error or module that I can mention, I know this is hard to understand without knowing the actual error but I am actually looking for an approach that can handle this kind of situation :)