# Keep server gateway alive when pushing code to production

Tags: express, nginx, amazon-ec2

So this is something that I have come across lately because this happens to me often and it's kind of annoying having to let everyone in the office know that the server is going to be down due to me pushing code to production.  This usually only happens during hot fixes/bug fixes.  I searched online for this question but there wasn't really much out there on how to do something like this.  Is there a way to keep the server gateway up while I'm pushing code to production without it interrupting the service?

I'm running a `React` application that uses `express` which is hosted on an `AWS EC2` server which is where I pull code and restart the application.  I also use `NGINX` as the gateway to my server if that helps any.

The only thing that I could think of is if there was a way that while I'm pushing the new code the server recognizes that the application was interrupted and uses the old code.  After the new code is pushed, it would recognize that the application is running again but instead runs it with the new code without interrupting the service.

This might be a very vague description, but hopefully someone understands what I'm trying to get at here.  If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically need multiple instances of your server running so you configure a router or load balancer so that one instance is the primary instance (taking all the incoming requests) and when the other is done serving any requests it was processing, you can stop it and upgrade it, then start the new upgraded server and then reverse the process to upgrade the other instance.

The two instances can either always be running and each serving some new requests or the 2nd instance can be used only during the upgrade process.

Here's a simplified sequence:

1. Create upgraded server instance (in a new directory location on your disk)
2. Start that server
3. Configure your load balancer or router to route all new incoming requests to your newly upgraded and started server instance
4. Wait until the original server instance is done serving all requests it was processing (it should be getting no new incoming requests at this point) and then shut it down.
5. If you are only going to keep one server instance running at a time, then remove the code for the original server instance so it doesn't accidentally get used again and so you're only using the newly upgraded instance.

Comment: This is good information.  Do you have a resource that I could look at that would go more in depth about this process?

Comment: @Michael - Some references: [Updatng nodejs in production with zero downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976145/update-nodejs-in-production-with-zero-downtime) and [Using clustering for zero downtime](https://itnext.io/creating-a-zero-downtime-cluster-in-nodejs-ad879ee3160).  A google search for [zero downtime nodejs upgrades](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS880US880&sxsrf=ALeKk00wKzCPGOy7iMdHD8kS1Ed8btspSg%3A1598024946011&ei=8uw_X-0Ykc7Q8Q-txYyICA&q=zero+downtime+ugrades+nodejs) yields more articles.

Comment: What are your thoughts on using ```pm2```?.  That looks like something that could satisfy what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Michael - I don't have any experience with it.